# Can't share link due to privacy settings?

Tags: facebook

I've set up an app on facebook, and it is now live. Everything is working as expected and I can use the FB JS SDK to trigger a feed popup dialog, which also works great.

The problem is when I try to trigger a share popup dialog. In the dialog it states:

> Some people may not be able to see this attachment because of its privacy settings.

The link itself is pretty simple, and is in the form of:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?display=popup&app_id={app_id}&link={redirect url - same url as the app}&picture={some jpg - same domain as app}&name={name}&caption={caption}&description={description}
```

I've looked over all the settings of the app, it's a page app not a canvas app, and nothing seems to be out of place. What should I do?